# How can I access the contents of a StatefulWidget's State during a unit test?

Tags: flutter

I have a StatefulWidget (call it `MyWidget`) whose State (`MyWidgetState`) has a field `myData` which is initialized during `initState()` as follows:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myData = new myData(config.someField.getId());
}
```

When the user presses a button, myData is added to or removed from a global list.

I'm trying to write a unit test to test this behavior but I don't know how to get access to a MyWidgetState.  I tried including this in the setup():

```
widget = MyWidget();
widgetState = widget.createState(); 
widgetState.init();
```

but it crashes every time when it tries to initState(), complaining that "someField was called on null".  That's fine. I was probably cheating by trying to do it that way and I ought to do something with a WidgetBuilder or launch an application using MyWidget and then find MyWidget in the tree once it's properly instantiated.

If I do all of that, once I do how can I access that MyWidget's MyWidgetState to get a copy of myData and compare it to the global list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the widget using `tester.pumpWidgets`, then use `tester.state(find.foo)` to find the `State` (where `find.foo` is a finder that finds the widget). See the `WidgetTester` documentation for more options.

Comment: can you give an example. your answer is not as clear

Comment: I do agree with @MrDumb, your answer is not completely clear.

Comment: find.foo, while commented about, is not defined.

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand without the context of a working example.

Answer (score 29):

You can create a state and then access it's content.
Following [Ian Hickson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432455/ian-hickson) answer. hereunder is an example for the implementation:

```
final MyWidgetState myWidgetState = tester.state(find.byType(MyWidget));
```

Then you can access the state content:

```
myWidgetState.myData;
```

You can find more examples in the Flutter's [repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/stateful_components_test.dart).

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer. However, you're missing something. In order for accessing the state properties correctly, when you get the state you have to specify the state's type: `tester.state<MyWidgetState>(find.byType(MyWidget));` Then, you would be able to access its properties without any errors popping up.

Comment: I was wrong in my previous comment but cannot edit it. You're answer is completely correct, you only have to specify the state type if you declare the variable as `final` (and let Flutter infer the type). If you write `final MyWidgetState` as you stated it's perfectly correct :)

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand without the context of a working example.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to write a unit test on one of the methods of your widget's state, here's how it can be done:

```dart
// Assuming your stateful widget is like this:
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({this.someParam, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String someParam;

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

@visibleForTesting
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int methodToBeTested() {
    // dummy implementation that uses widget.XXX
    if (widget.someParam.isEmpty) return 0;
    return 1;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return ...
  }
}

// In your test file
void main() {
  test('if widget.someParam is empty, do something', () {
    const widget = MyWidget(someParam: '');
    final element = widget.createElement(); // this will set state.widget
    final state = element.state as MyWidgetState;
    expect(state.methodToBeTested(), 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Actually, if you don't need the `element` or the `widget` you can just use `final state = widget.createState();` without going through the element. And you won't need the case.

Answer (score 3):

If you use any code snippets to create a stateful widget in Flutter, you might have noticed that the state class created by Flutter is a private class which is maked by an underscore in the beginning. This is good because such classes are not meant to be used outside the library - well except for testing.

In widget/integration testing, you might wish to access the variables of the state class. In such case,  marking the state class as private would mean that you cannot directly access those variables. This may not be desired. To get the best of both worlds, we can use `@visibleForTesting` decorator.

An example is given below.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CounterWidgetState createState() => CounterWidgetState();
}

@visibleForTesting
class CounterWidgetState extends State<CounterWidget> {
  int counter;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var rndGen = Random(79);
    counter = rndGen.nextInt(96);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            key: Key('incrementButton'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                counter++;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              'Increment($counter)',
            )));
  }
}
```

The documentation for `@visibleForTesting` says

> Used to annotate a declaration that was made public, so that it is
> more visible than otherwise necessary, to make code testable.
>
> Tools, such as the analyzer, can provide feedback if
>
> the annotation is associated with a declaration not in the lib folder
> of a package, or a private declaration, or a declaration in an unnamed
> static extension, or the declaration is referenced outside of its
> defining library or a library which is in the test folder of the
> defining package.

The key takeaway here is that the Dart analyzer will warn you if you use your public state class outside your library or tests, which is seldom a requirement in Flutter design.

The idea of using `visibleForTesting` came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219882/1620779)

Comment: Can you access them with reflection or some other hacky solution so they are still private code-wise ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one full, working example of **testing state values** in a **widget test**.

This might not be the ideal approach since both the *widget state* and *state variable* are public, but it works. Specifically, ensure that both the widget state and state variables are public for the test to access them, so no leading underscore (`_`).

### App/widget definition with public state/state variable

```dart
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

// Note: this must not be a private member,
// so no leading underscore (_)
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Note: this must not be a private member,
  // so no leading underscore (_)
  int counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Unit test that accesses a public state variable

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:state_test/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('HomePage counter increments when + button pressed', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());

    // Get widget state for validation
    final MyHomePageState myHomePageState =
        tester.state(find.byType(MyHomePage));

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0
    expect(myHomePageState.counter, 0);

    // Tap the '+' icon to increment the counter
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented
    expect(myHomePageState.counter, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: What if the state class is private and also counter is private `_counter` ?